# Symfony2 Catchable Fatal Error: set method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-forms

I try to write on db but i receive this error when i write this code:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $id_user = $request->get('id_user');
    var_dump($id_user);
    $prova = intval($id_user);
    $entity = new UserDigitalPr();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity->setIdUser($prova);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();



    return $this->render('DtPyramidBundle:UserDigitalPr:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
    ));
}
```

This is the error:
**Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr::setIdUser() must be an instance of Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User, integer given, called in /var/www/it.virtuego.com/src/Dt/PyramidBundle/Controller/UserDigitalPrController.php on line 70 and defined**

IN my entity i have this:

```
class UserDigitalPr
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 *
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="digitalpr")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $id_user;

/**
 *
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="imtheboss")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="become_from", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $become_from;

/**
 * Set id_user
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUser
 * @return UserDigitalPr
 */
public function setIdUser(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $idUser = null)
{
    $this->id_user = $idUser;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get id_user
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getIdUser()
{
    return $this->id_user;
}

/**
 * Set become_from
 *
 * @param \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $becomeFrom
 * @return UserDigitalPr
 */
public function setBecomeFrom(\Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User $becomeFrom = null)
{
    $this->become_from = $becomeFrom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get become_from
 *
 * @return \Dt\EcBundle\Entity\User 
 */
public function getBecomeFrom()
{
    return $this->become_from;
}
}
```

In User Entity i have this :

```
/* ######################################################################## */
/* #############          Tabella user_digital_pr              ############ */
/* ######################################################################## */

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr", mappedBy="id_user")
 * */
private $digitalpr;

/**
 * L'utente che ha promosso un'altro utente a digital pr
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr", mappedBy="become_from")
 */
private $imtheboss;
```

And getter / setter method like this:

```
  /**
 * Set digitalpr
 *
 * @param \Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr $digitalpr
 * @return User
 */
public function setDigitalpr(\Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr $digitalpr = null) {
    $this->digitalpr = $digitalpr;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get digitalpr
 *
 * @return \Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr 
 */
public function getDigitalpr() {
    return $this->digitalpr;
}

/**
 * Set imtheboss
 *
 * @param \Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr $imtheboss
 * @return User
 */
public function setImtheboss(\Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr $imtheboss = null) {
    $this->imtheboss = $imtheboss;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imtheboss
 *
 * @return \Dt\PyramidBundle\Entity\UserDigitalPr 
 */
public function getImtheboss() {
    return $this->imtheboss;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an entity object instance, so you can find it and set as follow:

```
    // your entity namespace 
    $userObj = $em->getRepository("DtPyramidBundle:User")->find($id_user);
    $entity = new UserDigitalPr();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity->setIdUser($userObj);
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
```

Hope this help

Comment: '$id_user = $request->get('id_user');
        var_dump($id_user);
        $userObj = $em->getRepository("DtPyramidBundle:UserDigitalPr")->find($id_user)
        $entity = new UserDigitalPr();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity->setIdUser($userObj);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();'

I edit but i receive an error **Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '$entity' (T_VARIABLE)** on line $entity = new UserDigitalPr(); ... Why?? @Matteo

Comment: Hi @LucaM I'm missing a `;` :)  but check the correct entity namespace passed at the `getRepository` method

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a numeric value to `setIdUser`, you must pass an entity reference. This can be done by first retrieving the entity and then setting it as parameter.

But if you just need the entity for setting that value, you can as well pass a *reference* to the entity:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entity->setIdUser($em->getReference($user_id));
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

By the way, the corresponding entity field should not be named `$id_user`, because it does not contain the ID of the user (from the perspective of your code), but the actual user object. That’s the whole point of using an ORM.